# Creating a simple math gui program using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python, can not understand what's wrong with this code
Here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\sarvinoz.toshpulotov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__

    return self.func(*args)

File "C:/Users/sarvinoz.toshpulotov/Desktop/PROJECT2/Project.py", line 34, in getter

     a[int(coef1.get())] = int(pow1.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

and here is part of my code:

```python
from tkinter import *

class Derivat:

    def length():
        l = w
        global numb
        frame1 = Frame(l)
        title = Label(frame1, text = "Enter the length of your expression:", font= ("arial", 14), bg = "skyblue")
        title.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        numb = Entry(frame1, width = 10)
        numb.grid(row=0, column=2)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP, pady=5, padx=5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)
        result = Button(frame1, text="Enter:", bg="green")
        result.grid(row=0, column=3, padx =10, pady =10)
        result.config(command=Derivat.getter)

    def getter():
        m = w
        f = int(numb.get())
        frame2 = Frame(m)
        frame3 = Frame(m)
        a = {}
        coef = Label(frame2, text="Enter your coefficients accordingly:")
        coef.grid(row=0, column=0)
        power = Label(frame3, text="Enter the power's of the x accordingly:")
        power.grid(row=10, column=0)
        for i in range(f):
            coef1 = Entry(frame2)
            coef1.grid(row=20, column=i)
            pow1 = Entry(frame3)
            pow1.grid (row = 30, column = i)
            a[int(coef1.get())] = int(pow1.get())
        frame2.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        frame3.pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        print(a)
```

Comment: You do `int(coef1.get())` when `coef1` is empty. So this is the same as doing `int("")`, which gives the error you see. The same goes for `pow1`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I fix the problem? I want to create a table with two rows and n-columns and make a dictionary from those value? Thanks in advance?

Comment: You seem to think that using `.get()` is dynamic. When you do `val = entry.get()`, `val` gets the value of the entry at that moment, `val` doesn't change when the contents of the entry change. Therefore, you should wait with calling `.get()` until the moment you actually want to know the contents of the entry. This should be upon some event, for example when a button is pressed.

Comment: Then still, a user could press that button before filling in any entry or filling them with text, so you should make some effort to either force the entry to only accept integers or check whether the contents you get are of the form you expect them to be before using them.